# Svelte - Prevent re-rendering when updating a value

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm doing a CSS-based custom animation as shown below, but I do not want to animate on the initial render. At first, I thought I could easily achieve this creating a new flag that gets set on mount. However, I'm not sure how I can achieve this because all variables I create at the top level will cause re-render when it's updated.

I read that anything declared at the top level will cause re-rendering on assignments. So, I'm forced to create this flag inside a function, but doing so doesn't let me access the variable in HTML. How can I achieve this?

```js
    <script lang="ts">
      import { onMount } from 'svelte';
      import classnames from 'classnames';

      let element: HTMLDivElement;
      let mounted = false;

      onMount(() => {
        const animationEndHandler = () => {
          element.classList.remove(animation);
        };
        element.addEventListener('animationend', animationEndHandler);

        mounted = true; // This needs to not cause re-rendering.

        return () => {
          element.removeEventListener('animationend', animationEndHandler);
        };
      });

      export let animate: boolean;
      export let animation: string;
    </script>

    <div
      class={classnames('animated', { [animation]: animate && mounted })} // <== This attaches the variable `animation` when `animate && mounted` is true.
      bind:this={element}
    >
      <slot />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating an integer counter and validate that it's greater than 0. This is ugly, but I can't find any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `class` directive on element, if you add the 'class' in the onMount, should work right?  (only thing, we need additionally to add the css animation class name(s) to `:global()` scope, as svelte might remove unused css classes).

```svelte
<script>
    onMount(() => {
        const animationEndHandler = () => {
            element.classList.remove(animation);
        };
        element.addEventListener('animationend', animationEndHandler);

        element.classList.add(animation);

        return () => {
            element.removeEventListener('animationend', animationEndHandler);
        };
    });
</script>
```